# Running python script via execute command from shell in Jenkins

Tags: python, jenkins

The Jenkins job is set up so that it checks out latest version of a git repo 
which executes some python code. The git repo is checked out to our linux lab pc and it runs there.

In the script, we are checking status of some labpc network interfaces. I made a small script which executes the following lines but it throws error like "no file or directory." The command is ok but it fails because linux env is not visible. The strange thing is that we have like 10 testcases and in 6 of them it works perfectly fine and it 4 it fails and it always fails for just those. The sequence of events is exactly the same in all the testcases ...

```
res = subprocess.check_output(['ip', 'link', 'show', 'dev', '<interface name>'])
logger.info(res)
```

The scripts works when executed locally so there is jenkins issue which is behind this. Does anybody have any tips to resolve this?

Comment: this is your python script, how do you call the python script in your Jenkins Job ? There is also a log for your Job inside Jenkins, you can see what happens there.

Comment: I just call it with python <absolute path>/<script name>. I don't know what more the jenkins logs will show. I will check. I'm trying to understand the reasoning but I have no idea.

Comment: I mean do you call it via **executable shell command** or part of a groovy script `sh  python <absolute path>/<script name>` (sh for linux shell)

Comment: Yes its part of execute shell command. I solved the issue now. Thanks for help anyway

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by putting 'sudo' before the command. Even
though the command doesn't require sudo rights,  it requires it
when run with jenkins.

You can open in jenkins the node where you can execute groovy commands to the server and test that it works.